# What does "rogue for faith" mean?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, british-english, archaic-language

It's definitely some kind of an idiom. But i haven't clue what does "rogue for faith" mean.

Sry for the lack of additional information. Yes it's from Barry Lyndon. And it was pronounced during a toast to marriage. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Hi Strider, have you looked up the definition of 'rogue'? Where did you find this turn of phrase?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what is meant unless you tell us in what context you found the expression.

Comment: It's _Barry Lyndon_ (Thackeray). Other questions from this person suggest the film rather than the book.. The line is _Kiss her, Jack, you rogue: for ‘faith you’ve got a treasure!_ (see the colon?) 'Rogue' is being used affectionately,  'for 'faith' was a mild religious oath at the time meaning something like 'I swear by my faith in God', and the 'treasure' is Nora, whom Captain Quin hopes to marry.

Comment: Michael, thank you sir! There was no colon in subtitles... With the colon it's very clear. Now i see what it means. Ur answer is complete and very helpful, indeed.

Comment: Suggest you try [reading the book](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4558/pg4558-images.html)

Comment: Note that the cited use of ***faith*** is essentially ***Irish***. In Kubrick's movie the word occurs twice, as *Kiss her, Jack, for faith you've got a treasure* and *Faith, and I believe ye!* In both cases most native speakers would automatically assume those words were spoken in an Irish accent if they read them. For most Irish speakers, *[for] **faith*** is just a fairly meaningless "discourse marker" equivalent to a modern Englishman's ***truly, indeed*** (or ***verily*** a few centuries ago! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - People in England sometimes said _i'faith_ which is similar. I like saying _by saint Loy'_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: ***i'faith*** is pretty much *medieval* in mainland Britain, but I think there are still plenty of people using it in Ireland even today. Or perhaps I'm just being influenced by the fact that the British *entertainment* industry uses it as "shorthand" for *rustic Irish speaker here* (like they'd have us believe the Irish always used to pronounce the f-word ***feck***, whereas in reality it was primarily introduced in the *Father Ted* TV series to get round censorship! :) I read Brendan Behan's *Borstal Boy* as a 12-year-old, and it was always transcribed as ***fugh*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Most of the people (apart from the author) in _Borstal Boy_ were British, I thought. I was 13 when I read it. . Re-read it a couple of months ago. Still as fresh. The gay incident passed me by the first time. He says 'You wouldn't have come through that door so shagging easy if I did' when the cop asks him if he has a gun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you too! Very informative. I've already managed to understand it's an Irish way of speaking.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I take that as further evidence that we're living in a simulation that's running out of compute! It's been on my mind for a couple of years now to pick up a copy of *Borstal Boy* and re-read it. I haven't ***re**-read* a book in decades, but I recently bought Russell Hoban's *The Lion of Boaz-Jachin and Jachin-Boaz* (1973) online, and had it sent to my daughter. I'm expecting her to bring it to me in the next few weeks...

Comment: ... - I barely remember anything about it except I thought it was so good I went back to the bookshop the day after reading it, and bought 3 more copies for friends! It might be I think it's crap second time around!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it was an afternoon play on BBC Radio 4 not so long ago.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Excellent explanation, but I would suggest that _for =  because_ and the apostrophe represents _in_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Barry Lyndon (Thackeray). Other questions from this person suggest the film rather than the book.. The line is Kiss her, Jack, you rogue: for ‘faith you’ve got a treasure! (see the colon?) 'Rogue' is being used affectionately, 'for 'faith' was a mild religious oath at the time meaning something like 'I swear by my faith in God', and the 'treasure' is Nora, whom Captain Quin hopes to marry.

Note that the cited use of faith is essentially Irish. In Kubrick's movie the word occurs twice, as Kiss her, Jack, for faith you've got a treasure and Faith, and I believe ye! In both cases most native speakers would automatically assume those words were spoken in an Irish accent if they read them. For most Irish speakers, [for] faith is just a fairly meaningless "discourse marker" equivalent to a modern Englishman's truly, indeed (or verily a few centuries ago! :)

People in England sometimes said i'faith which is similar. I like saying by saint Loy' [though] i'faith is pretty much medieval in mainland Britain, but I think there are still plenty of people using it in Ireland even today.

I would suggest that for = "because" and the apostrophe represents "in".

Comment: Comments converted